# How to translate Lang::get('Reset Password Notification') in ResetPassword Notification for locale?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-fortify, laravel-translatable

How to translate Notification messages text? I found it's path,
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php' copied it's content to`  app/Notifications/PasswordReset.php`

```
protected function buildMailMessage($url)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
        ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
        ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
        ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
        ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
}
```

How to translate `Lang::get('Reset Password Notification')` string, where to put my translation, how to set locale?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the localization files int the `resources/lang` directory.
It is well explained in the documentation:
[Using Translation Strings As Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys)

> This works, but are any better options?

There is a nice package to easily manage your translations:
[Translation Manager](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager)

It provides a command to find the translations in the project files, it can also append the new translations string in the localization files and it provides a simple user interface to set the translations for the different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Currently found that I create '{locale}.json'. I put strings in  `resources/lang/lt.json`:

```
{
"Reset Password Notification": "Slaptažodžio priminimo pranešimas",
}
```

This works, but are any better options?